# Redirecting to html page from Spring Controller class

Tags: angularjs, spring, redirect

I am using angularjs and spring mvc for my application.I am doing payment gateway integration.The issue i am facing is after successful transaction or failure i need to redirect to html page.But right now i am not able to do so.

Here is the SpringController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getDonationDetails",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public @ResponseBody String getDonationDetails(@RequestParam String msg) throws IOException {
    if(updateTransaction!=null){
        return "redirect:/donate";
    }else{
        return "redirect:/donate";
    }
}
```

Right now i am using redirect.But it is displaying "redirect:/donate' in an empty page.
Here is my angular app.js code

```
$routeProvider.when('/donate',{
    templateUrl : 'static/front/donate.html',
    controller : DonateController
});
```

Can anyone tell how to redirect to donate.html page from return statement?

Comment: try removing @ResponseBody

Comment: If i remove @ResponseBody it is throwing error as RequestMethod POST Not supported

Comment: Remove RequestMethod Post and try

Comment: R u using `@Controller` or `@RestController`?

Comment: I am using @Controller.

Comment: Then you should either remove your `@ResponseBody` annotation, or return `ResponseEntity` instead of `String`. Something like this: `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY).location(new URI("/donate")).build();`

Comment: Which import do i have to do for HttpStatus?Is it org.springframework.http.HttpStatus?

Comment: It is throwing error at .status and newURI.Error is the method status is undefined for the type ResponseEntity.And same for newURI

Comment: yea i removed ResponseBody and in return "redirect:#!/donate".Now it is working.Thanks for reply